# Syntax for OR in gulp JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, regex, gulp

This *should* be easy. I have this path variable declared in a [`gulpfile.js`](http://gulpjs.com/):

```
paths = {
    img: [
    'src/patternlab/**/**/*.jpg',
    'src/patternlab/**/**/*.png'
  ]
};
```

I'd like to use a simple OR switch for the file extension, along the lines of:

```
'src/patternlab/**/**/*.(jpg|png)'
```

But I can't find the right syntax! Have tried numerous permutations, looked through [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) etc…

Comment: what errors are you getting, you already look good to go

Comment: no errors but no images output either!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The patterns used by gulp are those promoted by npm's [glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) package which doesn't use a precise regex pattern matching syntax, I imagine because these things start to look horrific when matching against paths.

the documentation regarding [minimatch](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch) (used by glob) cover your described case:

```
'/**/*.+(jpg|png|tiff)'
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this :

```
^src\/patternlab\/.{2}\/.{2}\/.\.(jpg|png)$
```

the regex you have mentioned will also match files which have file names like `some.png something else`.

try this in your console:

```
var newarr = []
var paths = {
    img: [
    'src/patternlab/**/**/*.jpg',
    'src/patternlab/**/**/*.png',
    'src/patternlab/**/**/*.tiff',
    'src/patternlab/**/**/*.jpg'
  ]
};
for(var i=0;i<paths.img.length;i++){
  if (/^src\/patternlab\/.{2}\/.{2}\/.\.(jpg|png)$/.test(paths.img[i])){
    newarr.push(paths.img[i]);
  }
}

console.log(newarr);
```

Comment: Thank you, will give that a go. What I really want though is something as simple as possible, as I'm reusing in a number of projects and with a number of people!